# XmlSerializer causing exception to be thrown in mscorlib.dll that is uncaught by .NET and the OS

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application running in Windows Embedded Standard 7.

There is an exception that gets thrown when I call `Serialize` or sometimes `Derserialize` that goes completely uncaught when being run on Embedded Windows.

This exception causes my application to exit without any way to stop it. I cannot catch the exception

Edit: I should note that it is not possible to reproduce this error on anything other than Embedded Windows. The `XmlSerializer` class is known to throw internal exceptions that are handled, which may be the case when I am running it on a desktop, but only in Embedded Windows do the internal exceptions of the .NET class go unhandled.

It is also important to note that a try/catch around the calls to `Serialize` or `DeSerialize` cannot catch these exceptions, as the .NET class is not meant to throw these exceptions outside of the class, but handles them internally (unless running on Windows Embedded Standard 7, which is my issue).

Comment: Please ask your question in the form of a question. Also the bit of code and classes that are causing XmlSerializer to explode would be very useful, once we find out what the question is.

Comment: Not sure I can find that in the rules. It said to be as specific as possible, and that's as specific as I can be. I'm not sure phrasing it in the form of a question would assist you in understanding the issue any further, and is likely to make the issue more convoluted. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The Serializer throws an exception when the content to be Derserialized has anything in it that is unexpected. Likewise it will throw an exception if a class that you're trying to Serialize is not Serializable.

Comment: No, they're not outward or thrown exceptions. They happen inside the XmlSerializer .NET class. This class is known to throw internal exceptions that are handled, but only when running in Windows Embedded does .NET/the OS not handle these internal exceptions properly. A try/catch around the call to `Serialize` will have no effect, again, as they are not exceptions thrown out of the class, but that are meant to be handled by .NET/the OS. I've added some more info to my post to explain a little better.

Comment: Is the failure consistent? Same value/object causes the explosion or is it seemingly random?

Comment: Yes, the object I am serializing and deserializing is always the exact same. The worst part is that because the error is completely uncatchable, remote debugging offers no help whatsoever. The application simply terminates itself and my remote debugging session ends, at best noting that there was an exception thrown in mscorlib

Comment: Also, I just purposely malformed the root of the XML document, and sure enough I got my popup saying 'There is an error in XML document (2,2).'. This is just to demonstrate that if I am actually doing something wrong, I've handled these errors myself.

Comment: Does it have to be XmlSerializer? Is Json an option?

Comment: At this point, I think you're right. I'm safer just doing a `File.WriteAllText()` rather than messing around with this class more.

Comment: I've had very good results with Newtonsoft.Json JsonConver. Unless you're pulling XML from the database engine or have someone sending XML to the app from outside your control you can change the way you store things.